# locking/unlocking shared memory array of integers

Tags: linux, memory, locking, shared

I have 2 large arrays of integers (2 dimensional) that are being stored in shared
memory.  A number of processes on Linux need to access these tables.  The operations
performed on the array elements is a simple -- or ++ operation.

Does the necessitate using semaphore locking/unlocking operations to ensure consistency?

Comment: Not necessarily semaphores, but some kind of locking. Or if your language supports them, atomic integers and appropriate operations.

Comment: Language being used in the app is C.  Lots of other structures in shared memory are being controlled via semaphores....not sure why this one wasn't.